# Socket.io not working in angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io

I am trying to learn angular with socket in a todo app. But socket is not working. I am using socket.io v2.0.3. but I am getting error in chrome console.

[image: Error screenshot]

My code is -

```
import io from "socket.io-client";
private url = 'http://localhost:3001';
private socket;

ngOnInit(): void() {
    this.socket = io.connect(this.url);
    // Receive Added Todo
    this.socket.on('TodoAdded', (data) => {
    console.log('TodoAdded: '+JSON.stringify(data));
    this.todos.push(data.todo);
  });
}
```

Comment: Ensure that the declaration private url = 'http://localhost:3001'; remains the way it is. If you append endpoints directory path name to private url (e.g private url = 'http://localhost:3001/api/';), you'll not be able to listen to or emit data to the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to import io like this instead:

`import * as io from 'socket.io-client';`

otherwise you do not know which export to use from socket.io-client. It has 
no default export.

**Side Note:**
You can use `this.socket = io(this.url)` instead of using the connect-method if you want to.

Comment: Also ensure that you keep your URL clean.  private url = 'http://localhost:3001';

Answer (score 0):

this problem sucked a lot of my energy the solution is  very simple . all of you guys who are working in angular6+ and using RxJS 6+ just do this 
in your **polyfills.ts** file just add this line

```
   (window as any).global = window;
```

hope this solves your problem